# Groovy get map value for item and return with parenthesis if found else blank

Tags: groovy, formatting, collect

I want to have a lookup list that returns the found value in parenthesis if found or else return blank string.  I do not want to use enum.

Like this:

```
def grt = { ['mail': 'Scanned Paper', 'digital': 'Digital Things', 'barcode': 'Some Barcode Matter'].get(it) }

def s = grt('digital') ? "($grt('digital')" : ''
println "Report $s"
```

But I want to do it simpler and eliminate the 'def s' line so that there is some kind of collect on the end of get(it) and it is all on one line.  I can do an elvis, but the doesn't put ()

I can even do meta programming such as:

```
Object.metaClass.prettyString = { delegate ? "($delegate)" : '' }
```

and then have to just do

```
println "Report $grt('digital').prettyString()"
```

There must be a kind of

```
.get(it).collect { it ? "($it)" : '' }
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it in one line:

```
def grt = { 
    [
        'mail': 'Scanned Paper', 
        'digital': 'Digital Things', 
        'barcode': 'Some Barcode Matter'
    ][it].with { 
        delegate ? "($delegate)" : '' 
    }
}

println "Report ${grt('digital')}"
```

Comment: Perfect, that is what I was looking for.  The 'with' method is exactly the answer.  Btw I originally used [it] but changed to .get(it) as it is more readable by others.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a default value when calling `get`.

```
def grt = { 
    [
        'mail': 'Scanned Paper', 
        'digital': 'Digital Things', 
        'barcode': 'Some Barcode Matter'
    ].get(it, '')
}

println "Report ${grt('digital')}"
```

Comment: I like this solution better

Comment: Jeff I preferred Emmanuel's answer as it missed the key requirement which is - if found put in parenthesis -- i.e. (Digital Things), otherwise just return a blank string.  But nice as I did't realize you could have a default result on get.